# Why is initial route not the only route on the stack after building Navigator?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

If an initial route is defined, Navigator builds the stack with two routes: the initial one and '/' route.

Check out the example on the [link](https://dartpad.dev/e3deced1cff8117e08e8dbd82ef92114) showing that HomePage as the initial route has a back button that returns to '/' route.

How to make an initial route the only route on the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you use, `switch`, you return the `null` in your `default`, which sets the `HomePage` as the `initialRoute`, and let the machine know that, the `initialRoute` is the one, and nothing to be returned in the `Stack`, except `HomePage`. Hence, you don't get to see the back button anymore.

```
   switch (settings.name) {
      case HomePage.route:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
      case OverviewPage.route:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OverviewPage());
      default:
        // this would do the job
        return null;
   }
```

I have made changes in the link also, you can try that too. Try out [this](https://dartpad.dev/e3deced1cff8117e08e8dbd82ef92114) link, and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try as this, initialRoute:**'/'**  in **MaterialApp**

```
 const String homeRoute = '/';
    void main() {
      runApp(
        MaterialApp(
          title: 'Example',
          initialRoute:homeRoute,
          onGenerateRoute: generateRoute
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: It works in that way, but I don't want the initial route to be '/'.